# How to exit from a C# recursive method which has return type

Tags: c#, recursion

My code is like the below one,

```
public object GetObjectValue(object obj, int condition)
{
     if(condition > 10)
     {
       //exit from method 
       // return; gives compiler error.      
     }
     else
     {
        GetObjectValue(obj,condition); // like this i need to use recursive call.
        //Do stuffs
     }
}
```

How to exit from this method.  Help me.

Comment: The most important question: What are you trying to do?

Comment: what is the error that ur getting?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some points:

1. You need to return something in either case. Even if you `return null` on `if(condition > 10)`, your next compilation error will say you need to return a value on every path (actually, that's the same compilation error)
2. `GetObjectValue(obj,condition);` may result in an infinite recursion - you call it with the same values over and over.
3. You cannot "do stuff" after a `return` statement - that marks the end of the executed code (unless you have a `finally` block, but that's another subject). If you don't want to `return` that value that's also great, but you probably want to use it somehow: `object returnedValue = GetObjectValue(obj, condition);`

You may be looking for something like:

```
public object GetObjectValue(object obj, int condition)
{
     if(condition > 10)
     {
       //exit from method 
       return null; 
     }
     else
     {
        IChild current = (IChild)obj
        //Do stuffs HERE
        return GetObjectValue(current.Parent, condition + 1);  recursive call.
     }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to return an object reference, or null.

```
public object GetObjectValue(object obj, int condition) {
    if (condition > 10) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return GetObjectValue(obj, condition);
    }
}
```

Be aware though, that this method is very prone to a stack overflow error because any value of `condition` less than or equal to 10 will never reach the *base case*, or *terminating condition*. Recursive methods need a case that returns a value without calling itself.

```
public object GetObjectValue(object obj, int condition) {
    if (condition > 10) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return GetObjectValue(obj, condition++);
    }
}
```

Now `condition` is incremented, so when the method is called, it will eventually progress towards a value greater than 10, satisfying the condition and returning null. This is still a useless method though, because it can only ever return the same value for any input; the only difference will be how many recursive calls it makes before returning null.

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to return an object:

```
public object GetObjectValue(object obj, int condition)
```

Either change the return type:

```
public void GetObjectValue(object obj, int condition)
```

Or use a valid return statement:

```
if(condition > 10)
 {
   //exit from method 
   return null;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have specified the return type as object, so have to specify the valid return type. Try the below code change,

```
public object GetObjectValue(object obj, int condition)
{
    if (condition <= 10)
    {
        GetObjectValue(obj, condition);
    }
    return null;   //return whatever object you have to return
}
```